# how can I get var in the script function?

Tags: javascript, html, alloy-ui

I want to get in js function value. how can i get them?

I use html and javascript and alloy-ui

I test in chrome developer console. staY.diagrambuilder or staY.Y or make function name.

```
<script>
 var staY = YUI().use(
    'aui-diagram-builder',

    function (Y) {
var diagrambuilder = new Y.DiagramBuilder({
            availableFields: availableFields,
            boundingBox: '#diagrambuilderBB',
            srcNode: '#diagrambuilderBB',
            fields: []
        });
console.log(diagrambuilder); //i want to access variable out of this script
});
</script>
```

how can i get diagrambuilder variable in chrome developer console?

Comment: `console.log(diagrambuilder);` ?

Comment: @Jaromanda X the variable is scored inside an anonymous function passed to the use function

Comment: console.log it inside `function (Y) {` ... the question just wants to get the variable to the console - so, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var diagrambuilder = null;
var staY = YUI().use(
    'aui-diagram-builder',

    function (Y) {
diagrambuilder = new Y.DiagramBuilder({
            availableFields: availableFields,
            boundingBox: '#diagrambuilderBB',
            srcNode: '#diagrambuilderBB',
            fields: []
        });
console.log(diagrambuilder); //i want to access variable out of this script

diagramInitialized();

});

function diagramInitialized() {
    console.log('If you are seeing this thenm diagrambuilder is available in global scope'); //it is accessible now;
    console.log(diagrambuilder); //it is accessible now;
}
</script>
```

Is this what you want?  @user9041996

Comment: While `diagrambuilder` **is** available in the global scope here, you're still using it inside the callback function. At that point, you might as well just make it be the argument to `diagramInitialized`, in which case now you're just doing the thing I wrote in my answer. Putting it in the global scope like this doesn't benefit you any, and personally feels more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You only have access to the `diagrambuilder` inside the callback function that you pass to `YUI.use`.

```
<script>
  var staY = YUI().use(
    'aui-diagram-builder',

    function (Y) {
      var diagrambuilder = new Y.DiagramBuilder({
        availableFields: availableFields,
        boundingBox: '#diagrambuilderBB',
        srcNode: '#diagrambuilderBB',
        fields: []
      });

      console.log(diagrambuilder);
      // use diagrambuilder here
    });
  );
</script>
```

If you don't want to put all of your code inside of the `YUI.use` function, you could make your own function that takes in `diagrambuilder`.

```
<script>
  var buildDiagram = function(diagrambuilder) {
    console.log(diagrambuilder);
    // use diagrambuilder here
  }

  var staY = YUI().use(
    'aui-diagram-builder',

    function (Y) {
      var diagrambuilder = new Y.DiagramBuilder({
        availableFields: availableFields,
        boundingBox: '#diagrambuilderBB',
        srcNode: '#diagrambuilderBB',
        fields: []
      });

      buildDiagram(diagrambuilder);
    });
  );
</script>
```

Another option you have is to create a function that takes in `Y`:

```
<script>
  var buildDiagram = function(Y) {
    var diagrambuilder = new Y.DiagramBuilder({
      availableFields: availableFields,
      boundingBox: '#diagrambuilderBB',
      srcNode: '#diagrambuilderBB',
      fields: []
    });

    console.log(diagrambuilder);
    // use diagrambuilder here
  }

  var staY = YUI().use('aui-diagram-builder', buildDiagram);
</script>
```

All of these do exactly the same thing, but the place that the code is written varies. Either way, the point is that you only have access to `Y.DiagramBuilder` inside the `YUI().use()` callback function.

You **can't do** something like this:

```
<script>
  var staY = YUI().use(
    'aui-diagram-builder',

    function (Y) {
      var diagrambuilder = new Y.DiagramBuilder({
        availableFields: availableFields,
        boundingBox: '#diagrambuilderBB',
        srcNode: '#diagrambuilderBB',
        fields: []
      });
    });
  );

  console.log(diagrambuilder); // undefined
</script>
```

And you **can't do** this:

```
<script>
  var diagrambuilder;

  var staY = YUI().use(
    'aui-diagram-builder',

    function (Y) {
     diagrambuilder = new Y.DiagramBuilder({
        availableFields: availableFields,
        boundingBox: '#diagrambuilderBB',
        srcNode: '#diagrambuilderBB',
        fields: []
      });
    });
  );

  // This will most likely be null, as it takes time to load
  // the aui-diagram-builder library, and the code is asynchronous.
  // If this does happen to work for you, know that you're getting lucky
  // and it will fail at some point. This is not something you should do,
  // but I think it's what you're hoping for, so I'm pointing it out.
  console.log(diagrambuilder);
</script>
```

Comment: sorry i already do it but i want to access that variable out of script.

Comment: @user9041996 you can’t. This YUI.use function loads in a library. You have no way of knowing when it’s all been loaded up. The only thing you can do is define a function that takes in `diagrambuilder` as an argument, and call that function just like I’m doing with `console.log`

Comment: @user9041996 I've updated my answer with more details.